# Populate a vector with multiple rows of a pandas dataframe without looping?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I have a dataframe:

```
dict = {'Names':['Jess','Tommy','Joe'],'Jess': [0,1,0],'Tommy':[1,0,1],'Joe':[0,1,0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
```

I also have all possible combinations for groups of two people:

```
combos = [['Jess','Tommy'],['Jess','Joe'],['Tommy','Joe']]
```

I want to find the sum of all the numbers in the dict for each combination. Currently, I can accomplish this with a for loop:

```
sums = []
for combo in combos:
  numbers = df.loc[df['names'].isin(combo),combo].values
  sums.append(np.sum(numbers))
```

This works fine, but it is slow once the number of combos gets large enough. Is there a way to vectorize this for loop and achieve the following-ish behavior:

```
numbers_vec = df.loc[df['names'].isin(combos),combos].values
sums = np.sum(numbers_vec,axis=1)
```

**Update**, I was able to increase speed by about 70% with list comprehension:

```
sums = [np.sum(df.loc[df['names'].isin(combo),combo].values) for combo in combos]
```

However, this is still the most computationally expensive step in the program. I am open to all suggestions about how to more efficiently navigate this pandas dataframe. Thanks!

Comment: The DataFrame will always be symmetric as you have shown?

Comment: Yes it will be!